# SOAP "POST" request (AJAX) in JavaScript (VUE) in Browser not giving right response

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap, vue.js, soapui

I have been trying to POST a SOAP request via $ajax (see below) to a remote web service. I am using unsecure Chrome and testing from localhost, the response is not what I am getting on SOAPUI.
I have tested the same service with the same parameters in SOAPUI and it works perfectly. In the browser I am getting a 200 code but getting an error code that is built in the web service. what am i doing wrong? does it have to do with the browser? AJAX?

```js
  data () {
    return {
     
      str: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">' +
        '<soapenv:Header>' +
        '<tem:ROClientIDHeader>' +
        '<tem:ID>{E5D6D2B8-3624-4959-872A-E536B213DCA0}</tem:ID>' +
        '</tem:ROClientIDHeader>' +
        '</soapenv:Header>' +
        '<soapenv:Body>' +
        '<tem:LeerlingService___FindLeerling>' +
        '<tem:Credentials>' +
        '<tem:Username>TONATHIU</tem:Username>' +
        '<tem:Password>tonathiu</tem:Password>' +
        '</tem:Credentials>' +
        '<tem:INSZNummer>8788041754941</tem:INSZNummer>' +
        '<tem:Naam>Redroban</tem:Naam>' +
        '<tem:Voornaam>Tonathiu</tem:Voornaam>' +
        '<tem:GeboorteDatum>1988-04-17T00:00:00.000Z</tem:GeboorteDatum>' +
        '<tem:EnkelZoekenOpINSZ>false</tem:EnkelZoekenOpINSZ>' +
        '</tem:LeerlingService___FindLeerling>' +
        '</soapenv:Body>' +
        '</soapenv:Envelope>'

    }
  },

  methods: {

    soapRequest () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'my web service',
        data: this.str,
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result)
        },
        contentType: 'application/xml',
        dataType: 'text/xml;'
      })
      
    },
```

Comment: problem solved! <tem:GeboorteDatum> should have been <tem:Geboortedatum>. Al3ways check what the backend is looking for. The strangest part was that SoapUI was coreccting that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
 <tem:GeboorteDatum>
```

This should have been `<tem:Geboortedatum>`. Always check what the back-end is looking for. The strangest part was that SoapUI was correcting that for me, and was not noticed.